# Conditional ui-view for "active" item in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Scenario:

I have a list of items rendered within an ng-repeat.

Each item has an item template.

When one of the items is clicked, that item becomes "active". That item then has a different template from the other items in the list.

By default, the first item in the list is "active".

---

Is it possible to use ui-router to accomplish this? I know I can use a templateURL function to get the state parameters, but then it would be applied to all items.

If possible, I'd like to avoid using ng-if/ng-switch since the active item would also have several possible nested states with different templates.

```js
angular.module("app", ["ui.router"]);

angular.module("app")
  .config(function($stateProvider) {
    
    $stateProvider
      .state("list", {
        url: "/list",
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: "list.html"
        controller: "ListCtrl",
        controllerAs: "listC",
      })
      // how to configure this to change template for "active" item in the list?
      .state("list.item", {
        url: "/list/item/:itemId"
      });
  });

angular.module("app")
  .controller("ListCtrl", function($state) {
      // this would be retrieved asynchronously
      this.items = [
        {id: 1, name: "One"},
        {id: 2, name: "Two"},
        {id: 3, name: "Three"},
      ];
      
      $state.go("list.item", {itemId: this.items[0].id})
  });
```

```html
<div ng-app="app" ui-view></div>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="list.html">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in listC.items" ui-view></li>
    </ul>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="list-item.html">
    <a ui-sref="list.item({itemId: item.id})">{{ item.name }}</a>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="list-item-active.html">
    <h3>{{ item.name }}<h3>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

take a look at http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref-active

you should do something like:

```
<a ui-sref="list.item({itemId: item.id})" ui-serf-active="active">{{ item.name }}</a>
```

Comment: This adds the class(es) you specific as the value to the `ui-sref-active` directive to the item. While that may help in changing the appearance of the item via CSS to make it appear "active", it does not solve applying an entirely different template for the item itself.